# Perform Animation In viewDidAppear On Objects With Constraints Set By Interface Builder

Tags: ios, xcode, animation, swift, interface-builder

I have watched the WWDC 2012 presentations on Auto Layout and read the documentation on the view appearance calls.

So I thought I needed to perhaps wait a frame or a second after viewDidAppear just to be safe, but still didn't work. Here was my code:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool)
    {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        view.layoutIfNeeded()
        view.autoresizesSubviews = false
        _textButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)
        println(_textButton.frame)
        let delay:Double = 4*Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)
        let time = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay))
        dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue())
        {
            self._textButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)
            println(self._textButton.frame)
        }
    }
```

This actually prints out (144.0,6.5,32.0,32.0) twice in a row. Which means even AFTER setting the frame to 0, it was set back to its constraint defaults.

Why is this?

I have another ViewController that looks almost the same as this one, with buttons having the same constraints. But when I close the view, I animate the buttons to slide out to the left with the following code:

```
@IBAction func takePhotoTap(sender: AnyObject)
    {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: animations)
        _camera.captureImage(receivePhoto)
    }


func animations()
    {
        var height = CGFloat(_distanceBetweenTopAndMiddleBar)/2
        _lowerLens.frame = CGRectMake(_lowerLens.frame.origin.x, _lowerLens.frame.origin.y, _lowerLens.frame.width,-height)
        _upperLens.frame = CGRectMake(_upperLens.frame.origin.x, _upperLens.frame.origin.y, _upperLens.frame.width,height)

        view.autoresizesSubviews = false
        slideOffScreenLeft(_gridLinesButton)
        slideOffScreenLeft(_swapCameraButton)
        slideOffScreenLeft(_flashButton)
    }

func slideOffScreenLeft(obj:UIView)
    {
        obj.frame = CGRectMake((-obj.frame.width), obj.frame.origin.y, obj.frame.width, obj.frame.height)
    }
```

This works JUST FINE! When they hit the button, these buttons slide off the screen. However when I load the next view I want the buttons to slide in from the right. But, as you can see above, even waiting 4 seconds before trying to set the frames of the buttons has no effect.

Can you suggest what I can do to animate some buttons to slide in the from the screen when the view loads? Why are the constraints overriding my changes in the first case but when I animated a View Controller before closing it with UIView.animateWithDuration the constraints were overriden?

Comment: You apparently didn't get the point those videos make, that you shouldn't set frames when you're using auto layout. You should be modifying the constraint's constant value, not setting frames.

Comment: I tried that before but I think I did it wrong. I will try that again now. I think I may have it this time!

Comment: You know whats interesting, if I set the width or height in the frame, it causes an issue, but if I do `_textButton.frame = CGRectMake(0,_textButton.frame.origin.y,_textButton.frame.width,_textButton.frame.height)` it doesnt! It seems but editing the dimensions of the button triggered my override to get re-override by the auto layout constraints.

Comment: Auto layout will cause your view to revert to whatever size and position is defined by its constraints when the view has to redraw itself. Setting a frame will change things temporarily, but as soon as the view needs to redraw, it will go back.

Answer (score 0):

When using AutoLayout, it is best practice to create outlets for your constraints and then modify the constraints, rather than the frames of your objects. I was having a similar problem. This also gets rid of the need for the dispatch_after call.

For example:
    @IBOutlet weak var buttonHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!

```
@IBOutlet weak var buttonWidth: NSLayoutConstraint!
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool)
{
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        // Modify the constraint rather than the frame
            self.buttonHeight.constant = 0
            self.buttonWidth.constant = 0
}
```

This will make the button 0x0. You can then do the same for the x,y position.